# Azure website redirection loop

Tags: asp.net-mvc, azure, web, http-redirect

I have an ASP.NET MVC application that runs on Windows Azure Website.

All of sudden the website started to redirect homepage URL '/' to itself causing a redirect loop. No change was made in the application at the time of the incident and log files don't contain any suspicious information - just lot of similar requests

```
2014-01-09 09:00:05 SITE_NAME GET / X-ARR-LOG-ID=581f1d91-727a-4820-a7fa-7c21888b5813 80 - 193.85.68.249 Mozilla/4.0+(compatible;+MSIE+8.0;+Windows+NT+5.1;+Trident/4.0;+Mozilla/4.0+(compatible;+MSIE+6.0;+Windows+NT+5.1;+SV1)+;+.NET+CLR+2.0.50727;+.NET+CLR+3.0.4506.2152;+.NET+CLR+3.5.30729) _ga=GA1.2.720579394.1386747761;+ARRAffinity=12ae470da6bd7ab5a7c446a8f29748ba5f73605e7fcd365292d61319cb67336f;+WAWebSiteSID=654ed6b99c9747759561e52c1f2cb0f8 - www.domain.cz 301 0 0 534 1069 31
2014-01-09 09:00:05 SITE_NAME GET / X-ARR-LOG-ID=3ddebc99-c083-4cbf-9bbe-90d755a8b1a0 80 - 193.85.68.249 Mozilla/4.0+(compatible;+MSIE+8.0;+Windows+NT+5.1;+Trident/4.0;+Mozilla/4.0+(compatible;+MSIE+6.0;+Windows+NT+5.1;+SV1)+;+.NET+CLR+2.0.50727;+.NET+CLR+3.0.4506.2152;+.NET+CLR+3.5.30729) _ga=GA1.2.720579394.1386747761;+ARRAffinity=12ae470da6bd7ab5a7c446a8f29748ba5f73605e7fcd365292d61319cb67336f;+WAWebSiteSID=654ed6b99c9747759561e52c1f2cb0f8 - www.domain.cz 301 0 0 534 1073 0
```

When I restarted the Azure website everything went back to the normal. The same problem occurred for the third time, so it probably isn't just a 'hiccup' of the server.

Can anybody help me with the problem diagnostic? I am kind of lost, because neither server logs nor application logs contains any useful information.

Comment: Do you have any custom redirect code in your application? For example to redirect to an all lowercase url?

Comment: Having the same problem on one of our sites for the past couple of days.

Comment: @rich.okelly: yes, there is a rewrite rule in web.config that redirects 'domain.cz' to 'www.domain.cz'

Comment: @LukasKabrt This seems like the likely cause of the issue (see the link posted in Cort's answer). It looks like MS are rolling out a fix for a problem that is theirs. In the meantime they have a stated workaround of removing any redirects to the site root. If this is not an option a temporary workaround could be to create a custom ActionFilter that does the same thing, just at a different part of the processing pipeline (obviously this will not be as performant as the redirect happening within IIS, but it will suffice in the short term).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See what Microsoft has to say about it here:

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/wpapps/en-US/ee3a5f97-8a58-4b42-a2d9-a73cd5d12c01/issues-with-redirect-rules-used-in-url-rewrite-feature?forum=windowsazurewebsitespreview

Answer (score 3):

You can use Application_BeginRequest to have the routing globally between non-www url to www url.

```
 protected void Application_BeginRequest(Object sender, EventArgs e)
 {   
   if (!Request.Url.Host.StartsWith("www"))
   {
      UriBuilder builder = new UriBuilder (Request.Url);
      builder.Host = "www." + Request.Url.Host;
      Response.Clear();
      Response.StatusCode = 301;
      Response.StatusDescription = "Moved Permanently";
      Response.AddHeader("Location", redirectUrl);
      Response.End();
   }
 }
```

Answer (score -1):

I realize that this is old.  But in my case this was due to an error in the code.

To get the real error to show I had to change this in the web.config

```
<customErrors mode="RemoteOnly" defaultRedirect="/Error/Index" />
```

To this

```
<customErrors mode="Off" />
```

It then showed me that